# error related to Tornado when calling bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, tornado

I am running a code using bokeh to display interactive plots. it was working fine until suddenly i get error related to tornado. I have installed latest version of bokeh and tornado but it does not solve the problem.the traceback is very long :

I am using pyarpes code developped for apres data reduction [pyarpes](https://arpes.netlify.app/#/):

```
import arpes
from arpes.io import(load_example_data, load_without_dataset, direct_load)
from arpes.utilities import default_dataset
from arpes.utilities.conversion import convert_to_kspace
from arpes.utilities.conversion import *
from arpes.fits import *
from pathlib import Path
import arpes.corrections
import arpes.plotting
from arpes.analysis import *
from arpes.provenance import update_provenance
#DIRECT DATA LOADING test 
p = Path('.')/'arpes'/'example_data'/'test.nxs'
load_without_dataset(p)
f = load_without_dataset(p, location='xxx')
data = f.sel(psi=2, phi=slice(-0.01, 0.07), eV=slice(95.2, 96.5)).transpose('eV', 'phi')  # pocket selection
data_mean = (data - data.mean('eV')) # background substraction
data_mean.S.show()

ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET /autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:52526&resources=none (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:52526', method='GET', uri='/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:52526&resources=none', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\views\autoload_js_handler.py", line 60, in get
    session = await self.get_session()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\views\session_handler.py", line 120, in get_session
    session = await self.application_context.create_session_if_needed(session_id, self.request, token)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\contexts.py", line 218, in create_session_if_needed
    self._application.initialize_document(doc)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\application\application.py", line 171, in initialize_document
    h.modify_document(doc)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\application\handlers\function.py", line 132, in modify_document
    self._func(doc)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\arpes\arpes\plotting\interactive.py", line 43, in tool_handler
    return self.tool_handler_2d(doc)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\arpes\arpes\plotting\interactive.py", line 225, in tool_handler_2d
    color_mode_dropdown.on_change('value', on_change_color_mode)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model.py", line 551, in on_change
    descriptor = self.lookup(attr)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py", line 492, in lookup
    raise AttributeError(f"{cls.__name__}.{name} property descriptor does not exist")
AttributeError: Dropdown.value property descriptor does not exist
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:52526&resources=none (127.0.0.1) 80.00ms
```

thanks for helping

Comment: can you edit your post and show some code!!

Comment: sorry about that added my lines

Comment: Looking at their [requirements](https://arpes.netlify.app/#/?id=requirements) section, their package is based on an *ancient* 0.12  version of Bokeh that is 5+ years and two major release levels out of date. Making things work with modern versions of Bokeh is is an issue for the authors oof the pyarpes package to address. You should file an issue on their issue tracker.  In the mean time all I can suggest is that you install the very old version of Bokeh listed there.

Comment: thanks. the traceback was indeed shorter but now i cannot launch Jupyter lab it is stuck asking to keep waiting or clear workspace. it seems to be related to the tornado version according to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6696 .

Comment: Perhaps this FAQ https://arpes.netlify.app/#/faq?id=i-want-to-use-the-bokeh-based-interactive-tools-what-version-of-tornado-should-i-use

Comment: indeed must stick to the requirements or may run into trouble with environment especially if update Jupyter on anaconda. also better run the install of packages under admin. thanks.